# Custom layout in toolbar not taking full width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I added a custom layout in my Toolbar but it's not filling the entire width of it and I don't know why.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f08f5.png

Here's the code for my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="360dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"></RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How to fix?

Comment: Do you have at least the basic on knowing what are you doing? I'm pretty sure you don't need to use the Coordinator Layout to achieve your goal.

Comment: Yes, because I need the scroll animation that CoordinatorLayout is required for, plus I plan to add a TabLayout later on as well.

Comment: I see the image the black area is the tool bar correct. This is already the fit to the width.

Comment: A RelativeLayout shouldn't be inside a Toolbar. That has no sense.

Comment: What it means "RelativeLayout android:layout_height="360dp"

Comment: @joaquin No I think it is correct we can sure add the layout inside the toolbar. the thing is he has applied the height which is suppose to wrong. I  guess.

Comment: You can see his screenshot the black color is fill the screen this is nothing but due to of the toolbar height.

Comment: About the width of the toolbar i can see that it is already fit with the width.

Comment: @joaquin So then where should I put the custom layout?

Comment: @user5380833 Your plan is to dynamically add the view into the toolbar. Then it is correct. let me know so that i can give more idea how suppose to add into the toolbar

Comment: Even if you does not want to add the add dynamical then it is still fine. you can add your custom layout into the xml under the toolbar tag.

Comment: Have you tried returning false from `onCreateOptionsMenu` without inflating a menu XML?

Answer (score -1):

If you set minimum width of your child toolbar to a large value, it will grow until fills its parent view which in this case it's a toolbar.

So write following attributes in your custom toolbar:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minWidth="10000dp"
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added an explanation